# Как добавить функцию из React элемента в переменную

Tags: reactjs

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: ""
        }
        this.addText = this.addText.bind(this);
    }

    addText () {
        console.log("hello");
    }
    render() {
        return(
            addButton
        )
    }
}

const addButton = <button onClick={App.addText}>Add text</button>

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Когда я запускаю приложение, то функция addText не срабатывает по нажатию кнопки, в консоль ничего не выводится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Назови переменную с большой буквы и сделай функцией, передай в нее функцию обработчик:

```
const Button = (props) => <button onClick={props.onClick}>Add text</button>
```

В рендер выводи как JSX, и передай метод

```
render() {
    return <Button onClick={this.addText} />;
}
```

По хорошему `Button` должен распологатся выше над классом `App`

```
const Button = (props) => <button onClick={props.onClick}>Add text</button>

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: ""
        }
        this.addText = this.addText.bind(this);
    }

    addText () {
        console.log("hello");
    }

    render() {
        return <Button onClick={this.addText} />;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: То есть принцип действия примерно такой же, как если бы я создавал дочерний элемент?

Comment: Это он и есть. Реакту нужно построить виртуал-дом, для этого нужны компоненты. А если тебе зачем-то нужен статический метод класс можно как-то так `class App extends React.Component { static somMethod() {} }`

Comment: Тогда ты сможешь его вызывать как `App.someMethod();`